# How to send appointment through Outlook add-in?

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

I'm trying to implement an add-in for Outlook which has some fields and a button that once clicked does some validations and sends an appointment to inform the attendees.

I am using the function below to achieve my goal:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync()
Office.context.mailbox.item.close() (as a callback for the function above)
```

It works for office365, but it doesn't work for office365 thick client.

I found in the Microsoft docs that with the function 'saveAsync' in Outlook in cached mode, the item is saved to the local cache. I disabled this option and still getting the same result.

I was using OnSend functionality, but this feature is not supported for Outlook client.

Any advice or tips of how could I have the functionality of sending the appointment through my Add-in in both, client and web version of Outlook? Basically I need to trigger the existing button 'Send' in the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the ItemSend Event (OnSend) you are using in Outlook on the Web handles your scenario. We are working to bring this functionality to Outlook on Windows soon.